Implementation key press in Swift
I'm writing an application that will use your's phone as touchpad and simulate different touchpad's gestures by Swift code on Mac. But when I've tried to implement swiping between workspaces (same as three fingers swipe touchpad) due to it is possible to invoke with <kbd>control + arrow</kbd>, I faced with problem of invoking key press.
I've looked up to this discussion and wrote it like
func rightScreen() {
    let key = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: 0x7C, keyDown: true)
    key?.flags = .maskControl
        
    key?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
}

but it works just like simple arrow click. How can I make it work right?

An event tap shows that the arrow keys have the .maskSecondaryFn flag set (and fn-arrows don't). This code emulates the events of a manually pressed Control-Right Arrow:
func rightScreen() {
    guard let controlDown = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: 0x3B, keyDown: true) else {
        return
    }
    controlDown.flags = .maskControl
    
    guard let keyDown = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: 0x7C, keyDown: true) else {
        return
    }
    keyDown.flags = [.maskControl, .maskSecondaryFn]
    
    guard let keyUp = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: 0x7C, keyDown: false) else {
        return
    }
    keyUp.flags = [.maskControl, .maskSecondaryFn]

    guard let controlUp = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: 0x3B, keyDown: false) else {
        return
    }
    
    controlDown.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    keyDown.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    keyUp.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    controlUp.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
}


When posting a key press event, you need to consider both keyDown and keyUp events. keyUp has to be posted manually after a keyDown or the key will infinitely blocked.
So, use this instead:
func rightScreen() {
    let keyDown = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: 0x7C, keyDown: true)
    keyDown?.flags = .maskControl
    let keyUp = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: nil, virtualKey: 0x7C, keyDown: false)
    keyUp?.flags = .maskControl
        
    keyDown?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    keyUp?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
}

Reference: init(keyboardEventSource:virtualKey:keyDown:)

The reference also says "All keystrokes needed to generate a character must be entered, including modifier keys.". Can the Control down and up events be omitted?

@Willeke The modifiers are set in the flags option set

So the keydown and keyup event of the control key can be omitted? The documentation says "For example, to produce a 'Z', the SHIFT key must be down, the 'z' key must go down, and then the SHIFT and 'z' key must be released". Is the documentation wrong?

I tried this implementation and a bit variated, but for some reason it only works from time to time
but this part of code invokes always

@Willeke: Yes, you can ommit posting separate modifier key events if you set the flags. I don't know if that makes the documentation wrong.

@BrainPumpkin: What does not work for you?

@soundflix It should invoke control + arrow but mostly it is invokes just a simple arrow press and sometimes normal combination. I've also tried to separately invoke controlDown, arrowDown, arrowUp, and controlUp, but nothing changed.
